# How do you translate this joke?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

My native language is Spanish, but I speak English fluidly.
I was reading comics from http://customerservicewolf.com/ and couldn't translate the last panel of this one : 
[image: The phrase: "I knew I bought with me"]

The phrase: "I knew I bought with me". Or that's what I can read.
As far as I can tell, she was looking for a credit card or an id, it took so long that winter came, something like that (?

Anyway, I can't translate that phrase to a Spanish-friendly sentence.

How would you translate the last panel?

There's also a comment from the author underneath the comic in the original post:

> Flamingo carries at least 200 cards and has an uncanny sense of when you’re about to go on lunch :/

Comment: Do you mean "How do I translate a spelling error (and grammatical error)?" It should be "I knew I **brought** **it** with me."

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what the joke is meant to be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about a spelling error of the comic author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a misspelling, the word should be "brought".

The sentence itself (complete or not), as well as the note under the comic contain errors, so this is not the best example of correct English.

However, the meaning of the joke is that the bird is a customer that takes up a lot of time by looking for the right card after getting the wolf's attention. This is extremely annoying for both the wolf as well as any other customers waiting for him to be free to help the next one (or, as the note says, they do this right before the wolf leaves for lunch, delaying him).

The actual, simplified version would be something like, "I knew I brought it with me" or "I knew I had it with me", the bird says it because he just found the correct item (after searching for it for so long).